It is considered black hat SEO to use 1x1 <img> images to make CSS background images crawlable?
According to Google, GoogleBot does not index CSS background images.

Using standard HTML image elements helps crawlers find and process images. Google can find images in src attribute of  element (even when it's a child of other elements, such as the  element). Google doesn't index CSS images.

I have some photos as CSS background images on my site that I’d like to be findable on Google Images. Is doing this
<img src="…" alt="a search-engine-optimized description" width="1" height="1">

to make the images crawlable a good or bad idea?
I don’t think it’s deceiving search engines because the images actually exist on the page and I’m just providing metadata. Is this considered black hat SEO or bad practice?

It's not a very semantic approach.  Any reason you're wanting to do that instead of just submit an image sitemap?
